# Python-docx - Center a cell content in an existing table after adding values

Tags: docx, python-docx

I have a .docx template with an empty table, where I am adding values:

```
def manipulate_table():

table = doc.tables[0]

table.cell(0, 0).text = 'A'
table.cell(0, 1).text = 'B'
table.cell(0, 2).text = 'C'
table.cell(0, 3).text = 'D'
```

After adding these values, the the table attribute "Centered" is gone, which is standard behaviour.

How can I loop through my table and center all values again? I've already Googled, but found nothing helpful. E.g.: does not work:

```
for cell in ....????:
    tc = cell._tc
    tcPr = tc.get_or_add_tcPr()
    tcVAlign = OxmlElement('w:vAlign')
    tcVAlign.set(qn('w:val'), "center")
    tcPr.append(tcVAlign)
```

I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.text` property on a cell completely replaces the text in the cell, including the paragraph(s) that were there before.

The "centered" attribute is on each paragraph, not on the cell. So you need to do something like:

```
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
cell.paragraphs[0].alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
```

to each of the "new" paragraphs (assigning to `.text` will leave you with exactly one in each cell).

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me: table.cell(0, 0).paragraphs[0].alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT

Comment: @ProjektWeinheim: How is that possible? It would apply left aligned justification again, which you already got but did not want, according to your question.

Comment: `cell.paragraphs[0].alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER` worked for me

Comment: "The .text property on a cell completely replaces the text in the cell, including the paragraph(s) that were there before."

This should be in bold at the front of the API docs, instead of hidden away. Thank you.